# Python - loop through N records at a time and then start again

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-translation-api

I'm trying to write a script that calls `Google Translation API` in order to translate each line from an Excel file that has 1000 lines.

I'm using `pandas` to load and to read the values from a specific values and then I append the data frame to a list and then I use `Google API` to translate:

```
import os
from google.cloud import translate_v2 as translate
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime

# Variable for GCP service account credentials

os.environ['GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS'] = r'path to credentials json'

# Path to the file

filepath = r'../file.xlsx'

# Instantiate the Google Translation API Client

translate_client = translate.Client()

# Read all the information from the Excel file within 'test' sheet name

df = pd.read_excel(filepath, sheet_name='test')

# Define an empty list

elements = []

# Loop the data frame and append the list


for i in df.index:
    elements.append(df['EN'][i])

# Loop the list and translate each line
for item in elements:
    output = translate_client.translate(
        elements,
        target_language='fr'
    )


result = [
    element['translatedText'] for element in output
]

print("The values corresponding to key : " + str(result))
```

After I append to the list the total number of the elements will be 1000. The problem with `Google Translation API` is that if you are sending multiple segments they call it, it returns the below error:

> 400 POST https://translation.googleapis.com/language/translate/v2: Too many text segments

I've investigated it and I have seen that sending 100 lines (in my case) would be a solution. Now I am a bit stuck.

How would I have to write the loop to iterate 100 lines at a time, to translate those 100 lines and then do something with the result, and then proceed with the other 100 and so on until it gets to the end?

Comment: Your translation loop looks off, you are never actually using the `item`, only all `elements`, repeatedly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are able to pass a list into a single translate call, perhaps you could do something like that:

```
# Define a helper to step thru the list in chunks
def chunker(seq, size):
    return (seq[pos : pos + size] for pos in range(0, len(seq), size))

# Then iterate and handle them accordignly
output = []
for chunk in chunker(elements, 100):
    temp = translate_client.translate(
        chunk,
        target_language='fr'
    )
    output.extend(temp)
```